# Combine & with && shell

Tags: linux, shell, command-line-interface

I have this shell script in a php file:

```
[ ! -e "dsaasdas3efsdgadd345y5erhaha45_temp" ] && touch dsaasdas3efsdgadd345y5erhaha45_temp && wget http://localmyurltofunction?id=100 -O ./images/100 > /dev/null 2>&1 && rm dsaasdas3efsdgadd345y5erhaha45_temp &
```

I tested that in shell without the last & and it works great, but when I add the last & won't run, returning 1. I need a way to combine && with my &, I use that & because I want this process to run in background on a separate fork compared to my script.

Comment: This looks like a race condition waiting to happened. I assume the temp file is to prevent `wget` from running if another one is already running. However, you need to test and create the file atomically, or the following could happen: one process sees the file does not exist, but is suspended before it can create the file. Another process *also* sees the file does not exist, but is able to create it. When the first process resumes, it does not know the file has been created, but "creates" it anyway. Now both processes run `wget`.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to run the entire list in the background, not just the `rm` command.

```
( [ ! -e foo ] && touch foo && wget ... && rm foo ) &
```